# How to update 4 000 000 random numbers of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, sql-update

I have in total 10 million rows and I want to update random records with some values.

I want to update 4 million random rows with the `Datakey = 1`, the next 4 million random rows with `Datakey = 2` and the last 2 million with `Datakey = 3`.

I tried to learn some functions like `Rand()` and I want to use it in my request but I couldn't. I could only use the top 4 million to change them but I want random records not the first 4 million.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
update top (4 000 000) [FACT_INTERNATIONAL]  
set [DateKey] = 2
```

But I want the random 4 000 000 not the top. I am using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NEWID()` in `ORDER BY` like this:

```
UPDATE  X
SET [DateKey] = 2
FROM (SELECT TOP (4000000) *
      FROM [FACT_INTERNATIONAL] AS X
      ORDER BY NEWID()) AS X
```

> 4 Million records have too much cost in update, and sql may give an error after a while. Try with fewer records in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set datekey = (case when seqnum <= 4000000 then 1
                        when seqnum <= 8000000 then 2
                        else 3
                   end);
```

Note:  updating 10,000,000 records is an expensive operation so this will probably take a lot of time.  It is often more efficient to create a new table copying the existing data over.  However, your question is not about performance.